# Carcassonne: placing the fairy before or after the dragon hunts?

Tags: carcassonne

When playing Carcassonne with the exapansion the Princess and The Dragon when you draw a dragon tile can you move the fairy before the dragon starts to hunt? In my rules (in Dutch) the Dragon starts to hunt after step 1 (placing a land tile) is completed while on the WikiCarpedia it is mentioned that the Dragon starts to hunt after step 2 (placing a meeple) and is by consequence possible to place the fairy before the dragon starts to hunt.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**When you reveal a dragon tile, you place the tile, then place a meeple (or move the fairy), then the dragon moves.**

Moving the fairy replaces a meeple placement, and you may place a meeple before the dragon moves. From the [German rules](http://www.brettspiele-report.de/images/carcassonne/burgfraeulein_und_drache/Spielanleitung_Carcassonne_Burgfraeulein_und_Drache.pdf)

> Der Drache (12 Karten)
>
> Sobald eine Karte mit einem Drachen aufgedeckt wird, legt der Spieler sie wie gewohnt an und darf einen Gefolgsmann darauf setzen. Dann wird das Spiel kurz unterbrochen – der Drache zieht!
>
> *The Dragon (12 tiles)*
>
> *As soon as a dragon tile is revealed, the player places it as usual and may place a meeple on it. Then the game is briefly interrupted - the dragon moves!*

The rules for the fairy say:

> Immer dann, wenn ein Spieler in seinem Zug keinen Gefolgsmann einsetzt, darf er die Fee auf eine beliebige Karte setzen, auf der ein eigener Gefolgsmann steht.
>
> *Whenever a player does not place a meeple during their turn, they may place the fairy on any tile which already has one of their own meeples placed.*

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Z-Man rules [here](https://images.zmangames.com/filer_public/da/30/da30ce4e-814e-427c-b97b-2be3501961e1/zm7813_carcassonne_exp3_rules.pdf) The dragon moving is listed as phase 1b.  ie after placing a tile but before placing a meeple.

It also confusingly says

> Unlike Volcano tiles, you are allowed to place a meeple on a Dragon
>   tile. Then... the dragon moves which would appear to contradict 1b.

Looking at the original Rio Grande rules linked from BBG [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/25101/carc-pd-rulespdf)

> Whenever a player draws a tile showing a dragon figure, he places it
>   as he would normally place a tile, and may also place a follow on the
>   tile as he normally could.  Then, the game is briefly interrupted
>   whilst the Dragon moves.

As both sets of rules including wording that you may place a Meeple and then place the dragon I would go with that.

Comment: I wouldn't use the Z-Man rules for anything. Stick with [Hackworth's answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/50984/1050).